# SQL Server - GO n times

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Is there a way to vary the number when you use GO to repeat a statement?
I need to repeat some insert statements several times and I was wondering whether there is a more efficient way of doing it instead of changing the GO 100 etc  manually to the desired number each time.

Many thanks in advance.
K

Comment: Could you give an example? `GO` is not a SQL keyword, it's an IDE thing.

Comment: I *suppose* you could use a `CURSOR`. Depends what you're actual need is. Perhaps you could easily achieve the functionality with a Tally Table and/or Dynamic SQL.

Comment: I learn something new every time I come to SO...had no idea GO would resubmit the batch n times. I just thought it "signaled the end of the batch"...so I just gotta upvote ;-)

Comment: You can always _type_ the desired number. What else do you want?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with sqlcmd mode, which you can enable with `Query->SQLCMD Mode` in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. If I understood correctly you may have multiple occurrence of the GO statement and wish to vary the count without modifying all of them?

```
:setvar GOCOUNT 2

SELECT 1
GO $(GOCOUNT)
```